# swr fetcher configuration ignored

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, swr

I use swr to fetch user data. The request is accompanied by cookies.

The fetcher is configured for cors request as follow:

```
const fetcher = async (url: string, params?: any) => {
  const res = await fetch(url, fetchConfig)

  return handleResponse(res)
}
```

with `fetchConfig` as:

```
{
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors'
}
```

The first request is sent correctly with cookies, but the subsequent requests are sent **without** cookies, which results in failed(401) request.

I browsed the network tab of browser console and found out that:

- The first request is "initiated" by above fetcher snippet.
- The subsequent requests are "initiated" by `web-preset.js` as follows:

```
var fetcher = function (url) { return fetch(url).then(function (res) { return res.json(); }); };
```

Notice it's not using the configuration.
Does anybody have an idea why this is happening, or why the configured fetcher is not used at all except the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was actually using swr **inside** global swr config. Obviously configs are not in effect yet, so the default fetcher was being used.